# Can segmentation fault be caused by exhaustion of memory ?

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault

I am solving a problem on codechef.

I have coded the algorithm of the problem and it runs fine on the test cases. Although, when I run it on codechef(online), it throws segmentation fault.

I have double checked that, I am not accessing any inaccessible memory locations, although I suspect that my program could have taken up huge amount of memory.

So, my question is that Can segmentation fault be thrown, when there is no more memory available for the program to execute.  Something like `OutOfMemoryException` in C#

Comment: It could happen if you have a stack overflow, i.e. a large amount of automatic storage and/or deeply recursive function calls.

Comment: "*I suspect that my program could have taken up huge amount of memory*" you should better **know** how much memory your program consumes.

Comment: (1) usually yes, (2) usually no. The two answers are valid for the two languages mentioned in the tags, in some unspecified order. Please know which language you are using.

Comment: @alk How can I know exactly how much memory my program consumes, when I don't know in advance the amount of data which is given to it.

Comment: "*... you should better know how much memory your program consumes*" as a function of the input. If you cannot measure the input during run-time, you might have a design issue. As work around you might like to apply some logic which allows you to measure/monitor the total memory in use during run-time. @ps06756

Comment: @alk I am using a `vector<string>` to store the strings supplied in the input. How would I know how much memory it takes unless, I know the exact input.

Comment: @alk what, you mean the programmer should mentally solve the halting problem? :)   For example, if you wrote a program to search for counterexamples to the Goldbach conjecture that kept going until it found one.

Comment: You should know in terms of Big-O. If you need to read all N lines of the input, that's one thing. If you allocate N^3 strings, that's another thing.

Comment: @MattMcNabb it's OK to be able to give realistic upper bounds.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the way you allocate memory and whether you check for errors when doing so. E.g. `malloc` would return `NULL` on an out-of-memory condition. A failure to check that may lead to dereferencing `NULL` which would result in a segmentation fault. If you use `new` of C++, it would throw an exception instead.

In reality though when a program does excessive memory allocations it usually gets the system RAM overcommitted and its process is killed by an OOM killer before its `malloc` would start returning `NULL`s - unless most of the allocated memory is actually unused.

Answer (score 1):

As Kerrek mentioned in the comments an excessive usage of automatic storage or a call stack which is too deep can cause a SEG-fault e.g ([on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/abfed57cacc0053d)):

```
void foo(){ foo(); }

int main() {
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

or ([on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46eb21788011ac80)):

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int a[50000000];        
    std::cout << a[500];    
}
```

So to sum it up you have to be aware of your systems limitations, for example some recursive brute force solutions are sometimes *theoretically* OK and should work but are rather impractical (yes, this is a vague example but the OP did not mention what problem is being solved nor how so I wanted to give the above at least some context...).

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two situations

*1.* You try to allocate too much from the call stack, then you'll receive a signal. An exception can't be caught

---

```
int main() {
    try {
        std::array<int,10000000> arr;
        cout << arr[40] << endl;
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e) {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

*2.* You try to allocate too much dynamic memory, then you'll receive an exception

---

```
int main() {
    try {
        std::vector<int> arr;
        arr.resize(1000000000);
        cout << arr[40] << endl;
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e) {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can try it [live on ideone](http://ideone.com/UWpPaq).